# How do I properly set up has and belongs to many association in rails active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, psql, model-associations

I have 3 tables: `Tenants`, `Landlords`, `LeaseAgreements`

A User can be a `Tenant` or a `Landlord`.

A `LeaseAgreement` can have many `Tenants` and can have many `Landlords`.

A `Tenant` can have many `LeaseAgreements`. Same goes for a `Landlord`.

Right now, I am using the `LeaseAgreement` table as a join between `Landlords` and `Tenants`:

```
class Tenant < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :lease_agreements
  has_many :landlords, :through => :lease_agreements
end

class Landlord < ApplicationRecord
  include Token
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :lease_agreements
  has_many :tenants, :through => :lease_agreements
end

class LeaseAgreement < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tenants
  belongs_to :landlords
end
```

Should my `LeaseAgreement` table have a `Tenant` column and a `Landlord` column? If so, then how would I retrieve all `Landlords` or all `Tenants` from a `LeaseAgreement` record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need the associations between LeaseAgreement and tenants/landlords to be 1-to-many and not 1-1 you need two additional join tables:

```
class LeaseAgreement < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :lease_agreements_tenants
  has_many :tenants, through: :lease_agreements_tenants
  has_many :lease_agreements_landlords
  has_many :landlords, through: :lease_agreements_landlords
end

# rails g model LeaseAgreementTenant tenant:references lease_agreement:references
class LeaseAgreementTenant < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tenant
  belongs_to :lease_agreement
end 

# rails g model LeaseAgreementLandlord landlord:references lease_agreement:references
class LeaseAgreementLandlord < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :landlord
  belongs_to :lease_agreement
end
```

As you have set it up there can only be one landlord / tenant per LeaseAgreement as belongs_to uses a column on the model to store a single foreign key.

Comment: do you recommend using two additional models as a join in this case? I was thinking since both Tenants and Landlords are Users, I should somehow make the association between User and LeaseAgreement. I think I'm able to do this with polymorphic association, but this is where I'm stuck

Comment: You could use a polymorphic association but it has a lot of drawbacks. The greatest being the lack of real foreign keys to reinforce referential integrity and poor join performance. Polymorphism is a good hack for some cases to bridge the object relational gap but has no merit on its own.